# Chef Powershell output capture into attribute in latest chef 12

Tags: ruby, windows, powershell, chef-infra, iaas

Ok, so im stuck. I'm trying to read a .Net file's version attribute and save that into a node's attribute. So I can see the version of the intalled program on the server side in the node's attributes.

I can run a powershell script like this:

```
powershell_script 'filever' do
    code <<-EOH
       [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe").FileVersion > C:\\windows\\temp\\fileversion.txt
       get-content -Path  C:\\windows\\temp\\fileversion.txt
    EOH
end
```

I understand that the powershell and windows cookbooks are now part of chef's basic install, but it seems that powershell_out is missing. I tried including it like this, but no joy.

```
powershell 'filever2' do
  include Chef::Mixin::PowershellOut
  node.normal[:ixserver][:Hello] = powershell_out("echo hello")
end
```

I have all the little bits, but I can't seem to get them to gel correctly.

Comment: This has been followed up on the Chef mailing list. Please don't cross-post questions without good reason.

Comment: True, I did cross post, but I think its relevant to a wide audience , hence me making a question out of it..

Comment: Then ask only on here, getting two groups working on the issue in parallel just wastes the time of 50% of them.

Comment: Doubles his chances of a getting an answer though

Comment: I'd add that it's a benefit for the followers of both groups, isn't it? As long as the answer is posted in both, so people don't continue to waste time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the problem was that the file_read was running in the early stages of the recipe and not at then end when it was supposed to. Here is the working version for any that may need to read a file into a attribute and post it back to the server.

```
#Check the installed version
powershell_script 'filever' do
code <<-EOH
[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe").FileVersion > c://chef//fileversion.txt
EOH
end

#report back after all is done
ruby_block "reportback" do
  block do
    encoding_options = {
        :invalid           => :replace,  # Replace invalid byte sequences
        :undef             => :replace,  # Replace anything not defined in ASCII
        :replace           => '',        # Use a blank for those replacements
        :universal_newline => true       # Always break lines with \n
      }
      node.normal[:ixserver][:Version_Installed] = File.read("C:\\chef\\fileversion.txt").encode(Encoding.find('ASCII'), encoding_options)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for following up on this! I was trying to solve the same issue & approached the problem the same, but was having issues reading back in the text file (there were extra invalid characters read in). This explains how to get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how Chef works. Resources don't have return values in this manner and most can't set attributes. You'll have to use a ruby_block resource or LWRP, but the complexity of this makes it difficult to explain. I don't think `powershell_out` is an actual thing in Chef, did you just assume that exists because of `shell_out` or did you see it in the documentation somewhere?

Comment: There are many references to this on the internet, thats why I think it exists: for example: http://kapilshardha.blogspot.ae/2013/12/using-powershellout-mixin-in-chef.html

Comment: Ok, so the basic idea here is to make the recipe report success to the server. What is the appropriate mechanism for doing this?

Comment: Oh lovely, it does exist, because the windows cookbook is monkeying with the core Chef namespace https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/windows/blob/master/libraries/powershell_out.rb :-(

Comment: Remember this was before chef 12, and I didn't want to include this all into my chef and contaminate it :-) hence the question

Answer (score 0):

It's been moved to the windows cookbook.

From the [powershell cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/powershell):

> The Chef::Mixin::PowershellOut mixin has been moved to the [windows](http://ckbk.it/windows) cookbook.

And from the [windows cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/windows/blob/da01f07cc755798115689a6711f762afa6608bfa/CHANGELOG.md):

> PR 115 - require Chef::Mixin::PowershellOut before using it